# MVC 4 - back button issue after logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, browser-cache, back-button

I have read numerous posts where people have had similar issues but have not found a working solution. I have a MVC 4 site, I do not want to remove caching from the entire website as I want to cache the pages. When the user clicks the logoff button it successfully logs off and redirects to the login page, however when the user clicks the back button it shows a previously viewed "restricted page" which you should only be able to see if logged in. I understand that this is because the browser has cached the page client side. I have tried a number of solutions and as mentioned earlier none of them work. Currently my logoff has the following code:

```
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();

        // clear authentication cookie 
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        // clear session cookie (not necessary for your current problem but i would recommend you do it anyway) 
        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2); 

        // Invalidate the Cache on the Client Side 
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

        // send an expired cookie back to the browser 
        var ticketExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            // replace with username if this is the wrong cookie name 
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
            DateTime.Now,
            ticketExpiration,
            false,
            String.Empty);
        var cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("user")
        {
            Expires = ticketExpiration,
            Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket),
            HttpOnly = true
        };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); 

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how you are doing your authentication. But shouldn't every website be checking your database to make sure the user has proper authentication to be on the site? And if not, it should redirect him on display something. Even if your pages are cached your script would still run, and your user's session stored in the db should show him logged off.

Comment: Of course it's not going to work, your expiration code only affects whether or not the *current* request is cached.  The current request is your logoff code, so only the logoff page would be uncached.  You can't retroactively remove the cached pages after they've been cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the hash change event on the browser window, to trigger an ajax request on postback, this would obviously fail as your logged out. From there you could trigger the browser to do anything you like.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply the "no cache on browser back" behavior on all pages then you should put the following it in global.asax.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

hope it helps someone !

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines of code to *Global.asax.cs* file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, 
    must-revalidate");
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Expires = 0;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional information about *why* and *how* this code works improves its long term value.